# If I "get back to the main thread" then what exactly happens, and how do interrupts work with threads?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

Background: I was using Beej's guide and he mentioned forking and ensuring you "get the zombies". An Operating Systems book I grabbed explained how the OS creates "threads" (I always thought it was a more fundamental piece), and by quoting it, I mean it the OS decides nearly everything. Basically they share all external resources, but they split the register and stack spaces (and I think a 3rd thing).

So I get to the waitpid function which http://www.qnx.com's developer docs explain very well. In fact, I read the entire section on threads, minus all the types of conditions after a Processes and Threads google.

The fact that I can split code up and put it back together doesn't confuse me. **HOW** I can do this is confusing.

In C and C++, your program is a Main() function, which goes forward, calls other functions, maybe loops forever (waiting for input or rendering), and then eventually quits or returns. In this model I see NO reason for it to stop beyond a "I'm waiting for something", in which case it just loops.

Well, it seems it can loop by setting certain things, like "I'm waiting for a semaphore" or "a response" or "an interrupt". Or maybe it gets interrupted without waiting for one. This is what confuses me.

The processor time-slices processes and threads. That's all fine and dandy, but how does it decide when to stop one? I understand that you get to the Polling function and say "Hey I'm waiting for input, clock tick or user do something". Somehow it tells this to the os? I'm not sure. But moreso:

It seems to be able to completely randomly interrupt or interject, even on a single-threaded application. So you're running one thread and suddenly waitpid() says "Hey, I finished a process, let me interrupt this, we both hate zombies, I gotta do this." and you're still looping on some calculation. So, what just happens??? I have no idea, somehow they both run and your computation isn't messed with, 'cause it's single threaded, but that somehow doesn't mean that it won't stop what it's doing to run waitpid() inside the same thread WHILE you're still doing your other app things.

Also confusing, is how you can be notified, like iOSes notifications, and say "Hey, I got some UI changes, get me off of 16 and put me back on 1 so I can change this thing". But same question as last paragraph, how does it interrupt a thread that's running?

I think I understand the splitting, but this joining is utterly confusing. It's like the textbooks have this "rabbit from hat" step I'm supposed to accept. Other SO posts told me they don't share the same stack, but that didn't help, now I'm imagining a slinky (stack) leaning over to another slinky, but unsure how it recombines to change the data.

Thanks for any help, I apologize that this is long, but I know someone's going to misinterpret this and give me the "they are different stacks" answer if I'm too concise here.

Thanks,

Comment: I could answer, but it would be a long answer.  All modern OS thread schedulers are entered from running app threads via hardware and software interrupts.    You should read a good operating systems site or book.  You'll be lucky if your question is not closed as 'too broad'.

Comment: Thanks! I'm specifically wondering about the "interrupt" aspect, to me it's like 2 things occupying a single area. I'll read your answer when I'm more free. It seems I missed that part of the book if it's in there, may go grab it again (and read your answer :) ) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'll have a go, though it's gonna be 'economical with the truth':)

It's sorta like this:

The OS kernel scheduler/dispatcher is a state-machine for managing threads.  A thread comprises a stack, (allocated at the time of thread creation), and a Thread Control Block, (TCB), struct in the kernel that holds thread state and can store thread context, (including user registers, especially the stack-pointer).  A thread must have code to run, but the code is not dedicated to the thread - many threads can run the same code.  Threads have states, eg. blocked on I/O, blocked on an inter-thread signal, sleeping for a timer period, ready, running on a core.

Threads belong to processes - a process must have at least one thread to run its code and has one created for it by the OS loader when the process starts up.  The 'main thread' may then create others that will also belong to that process.

The state-machine inputs are software interrupts - system calls from those threads that are already running on cores, and hardware interrupts from perhiperal devices/controllers, (disk, network, mouse, KB etc), that use processor hardware features to stop the processor/s running instructions from the threads and 'immediately' run driver code instead.

The output of the state-machine is a set of threads running on cores. If there are fewer ready threads than cores, the OS will halt the unuseable cores.  If there are more ready threads than cores, (ie. the machine is overloaded), the 'sheduling algorithm' that decided with threads to run takes into account several factors - thread and process priority, prority boosts for threads that have just become ready on I/O completion or inter-thread signal, foreground-process boosts and others.

The OS has the ability to stop any running thread on any core. It has an interprocessor hardware-interrupt channel and drivers that can force any thread to enter the OS and be blocked/stopped, (maybe because another thread has just beome ready and the OS scheduling algorithm has decided that a running thread must be immediately preempted).

The software intrrupts from running threads can change the set of running threads by requesting I/O, or by signaling other threads, (the events, mutexes, condition-variables and semaphores).  The hardware interrupts from peripheral devices can change the set of running threads by signaling I/O completion.

When the OS gets these inputs, it uses that input, and internal state in containers of Thread Control Block and Process Control Block structs, to decide which set of ready threads to run next.  It can block a thread from running by saving its context, (including registers, especially stack pointer), in its TCB and not returning from the interrupt.  It can run a thread that was blocked by restoring its context from its TCB to a core and performing an interrupt-return, so allowing the thread to resume from where it left off.

The gain is that no thread that is waiting for I/O gets to run at all and so does not use any CPU and, when I/O becomes avilable, a waiting thread is made ready 'immediately' and, if there is a core available, running.

This combination of OS state data, and hardware/software interrupts, effciently matches up threads that can make forward progress with cores avalable to run them, and no CPU is wasted on polling I/O or inter-thread comms flags.

All this complexity, both in the OS and for the developer who has to design multithreaded apps and so put up with locks, synchronization, mutexes etc, has just one vital goal - high performance I/O.  Without it, you can forget video streaming, BitTorrent and browsers - they would all be too piss-slow to be useable.

Statements and phrases like 'CPU quantum', 'give up the remainder of their time-slice' and 'round-robin' make me want to throw up.

It's a state-machine.  Hardware and software interrupts go in, a set of running threads comes out.  The hardware timer interrupt, (the one that can time-out system calls, allow threads to sleep and share out CPU on a box that is overloaded), though valuable, is just one of many.

> So I'm on thread 16, and I need to get to thread 1 to modify UI. I
>   randomly stop it anywhere, "move the stack over to thread 1" then
>   "take its context and modify it"?

No, time for 'economical with truth' #2...

Thread 1 is running the GUI.  To do this, it needs inputs from mouse, keyboard.  The classic way for this to happen is that thread 1 waits, blocked, on a GUI input queue - a thread-safe producer-consumer queue, for KB/mouse messages.  It's using no CPU - the cores are off running services and BitTorrent downloads.  You hit a key on the keyboard, and the keyboard-controller hardware raises an interrupt line on the interrupt controller, causing a core to jump to the keyboard driver code as soon as it has finished its current instruction. The driver reads the KB controller, assembles a KeyPressed message and pushes it onto the input queue of the GUI thread with focus - your thread 1. The driver exits by calling the scheduler interrupt entry point so that a scheduling run can be performed and your GUI thread is assigned a core an run on it.  To thread 1, all it has done is make a blocking 'pop' call on a queue and, eventually, it returns with a message to process.

So, thread 1 is performing:

```
void* HandleGui{
  while(true){
    GUImessage message=thread1InputQueue.pop();
    switch(message.type){
      .. // lots of case statements to handle all the possible GUI messages
      ..
      ..
    };
  };
};
```

If thread 16 wants to interact with the GUI, it cannot do it directly.  All it can do is to queue a message to thread 1, in a similar way to the KB/mouse drivers, to instruct it to do stuff.

This may seem a bit restrictive, but the message from thread 16 can contain more than POD.  It could have a 'RunMyCode' message type and contain a function pointer to code that thread 16 wants to be run in the context of thread 1.  When thread 1 gets around to hadling the message, its 'RunMyCode' case statement calls the function pointer in the message.  Note that this 'simple' mechanism is asynchronous - thread 16 has issued the mesage and runs on - it has no idea when thread 1 will get around to running the function it passed. This can be a problem if the function accesses any data in thread 16 - thread 16 may also be accessing it.  If this is an issue, (and it may not be - all the data required by the function may be in the message, which can be passed into the function as a parameter when thread 1 calls it), it is possible to make the function call synchronous by making thread 16 wait until thread 1 has run the function.  One way would be for the function signal an OS synchronization object as its last line - an object upon which thread 16 will wait immediately after queueing its 'RunMyCode' message:

```
void* runOnGUI(GUImessage message){
  // do stuff with GUI controls
  message.notifyCompletion->signal();  // tell thread 16 to run again
};

void* thread16run(){
  ..
  ..
  GUImessage message;
  waitEvent OSkernelWaitObject;
  message.type=RunMyCode;
  message.function=runOnGUI;
  message.notifyCompletion=waitEvent;
  thread1InputQueue.push(message);  // ask thread 1 to run my function.
  waitEvent->wait();  // wait, blocked, until the function is done
  ..
  ..
};
```

So, getting a function to run in the context of another thread requires cooperation.  Threads cannot call other threads - only signal them, usually via the OS. Any thread that is expected to run such 'externally signaled' code must have an accessible entry point where the function can be placed and must execute code to retreive the function address and call it.

Comment: +1 You had me at "economical with the truth".  LOL I have to elevate that phrase to precede my conversations on many topics from here on in.

Comment: Hmm, most of this I tried to hint that I knew already, by talking about the thread blocking and stuff. But the TCB is new to me. But the tidbits you did give that I didn't know, I am piecing together, though there is still one thing: So I'm on thread 16, and I need to get to thread 1 to modify UI. I randomly stop it anywhere, "move the stack over to thread 1" then "take its context and modify it"? Then pop it off? Basically a stack on top of a stack, that delineates that its context is a different thread? If thread 16's registers are different, I'm puzzled as to how it changes thread 1?

Comment: And thanks a lot for the answer! Every little bit adds a piece to the answer. I just want to fully understand what I'm doing when I say "get main thread async" and "get main thread sync" then "run this piece of code when you do". So I know what variables are changing.

Comment: I'll make a quick summary... so if a processor is a road, then threads are lanes, and the stack functions would be cars. When I interrupt a thread, I'm not bumping cars over, but simply stopping them to temporarily put another car or cars there. This analogy should make it easy to pick apart the minor details for anyone who wants to help out. I used to think threads were the cars (stack functions) and when 2 = 1, something's wrong.